# Identify which region is what iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I have a question about `CLLocationManager` and `CLRegions`.
Lets say I want the user to select some localities and add a reminder when they arrive or leave, like Apple's application.

My question is, if I set the identifier of the CLRegion to "leave" and others to "arrive", if I have more than two regions with the same identifier, it will be overridden?

Do I have to store this location in coreData, so I can manage the add or delete functionality of the app as `monitoredRegions` does not allow delete?

Thank you